# Restrict Approle auth token to login to web ui in Hashicorp vault

Tags: hashicorp-vault

Let me explain my question with an example scenario.

If suppose I'm the admin of hashicorp vault. And I use WEB Ui for admin activities. And I create approle auth method for all my clients to authenticate with vault And fetch secrets through API method.
Question:
Now in this situation Will token generated by approle auth method, allow the client to login to web ui using Token method?

If so how to restrict this access because I want only admin to access vault web UI.

All answers are welcomed

Answer (score 0):

The UI is just another way to call the API. Behind the scenes, the UI calls the API using the Vault token you got by logging in. For example, you could log in the command line (with `vault login ...`), copy-paste the token in the UI and it would work.

Even if it was possible to do what you ask, one could write a brand new GUI (forking [Goldfish](https://github.com/Caiyeon/goldfish) or [Vault-UI](https://github.com/djenriquez/vault-ui) for example) and bypass whatever you would have put in place. You could also write a [Python script with HVAC](https://hvac.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) to access the API.

So put policies on the Vault **operations** you want to restrict, not the mean to access them.